# Unusual Infinite nested radicals

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, infinite-product

Find the value of 
[this infinitely nested radical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3dtc.png)
in terms of *a*. Is this even possible?

Edit: I believe that I have already solved it, though I would like confirmation that my work is correct. Here is my work for this question: [solution in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJgHC.jpg)

Comment: I believe I know the answer, though I would like to see if it is right. PS, I made up the question myself

Comment: You should include your answer as part of the question, so that people don't waste time duplicating your effort.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting links.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Blue, I basically did it the exact same way that Paras did it, though I just wanted to confirm that what I did was right because I have never seen an infinite nested radical like it. I will edit my question though, to show the work that I did

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Taking a^2 common you will get
$a^2\sqrt{1+√1+√1+√1+√1+...}$

Let y=$\sqrt{1+√1+√1+√1+√1+...}$

So,y=$\sqrt{1+y}$

Solve for y by squaring both sides

Comment: This is half: that if it converges, then we get the value.  But the other half is to show that it converges.